# laravel eloquent Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, helper

I building a helper in laravel to return a single field from eloquent.

```
class Helper {

    public static function getAddress($id) {
        //intval($id);
        $result = DB::table('tableaddress')
            ->where('id',$id)
            ->pluck('address');

        //dd($result);
        return $result;

    }
}
```

In the view i'm calling it via `{!! Helper::getAddress(112233) !!}` but getting an error of `Array to string conversion`.

Here is if the result of `dd`

[image]

How do I get the address to return a string. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get first result from an array, so use this:

```
->pluck('address')[0];
```

Comment: yeah, i need to return as a string. but your solutions return `Call to a member function first() on array`

Comment: Use `[0]` The `first()` method will also work if you'll use Eloquent instead of Query Builder.

Comment: This means there is no row is `id = $id` and it returns an empty array. You can check it with `dd($result);`

Comment: there is dd, refer to screenshot, it's the same but without the array only `"1-33 Jalan Jasa 8, Skudai, Johor, MY"`

Comment: So `->pluck('address')[0];` returns you a string as it supposed to do. Where do you get `Undefined offset: 0` then (check error message, because it shows where exactly you have an error)? Also, check your `Helper::getAddress(112233)` part, maybe you've added `[0]` there also.

Comment: no. just the `Helper::getAddress(112233)` in the view. sorry for this extensive comments

Comment: Look, you've shown string as result for `->pluck('address')[0];`, this means it works as expected. Look at the error message. It shows where is exactly the error (class and line number). Please check this and copy paste code from that line here.

Comment: here is the error `ErrorException in Helper.php line 12:` and line 12 is `->pluck('address')[0];`. I have choose this as an answer but I need to look at it first. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well @Shafiq which laravel you are using. Because I checked in Laravel 5 `dd($result);` gives string output.

Comment: @JaykumarPatil yep, I've also checked this in 5.3, works fine.

Comment: So the conclusion is that your code is correct, right ?

Comment: yes the solutions is correct. i'm using local db which is not updated. after some git push, the code work fine. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try it as:

```
{!! Helper::getAddress(112233)->first() !!}
```

Or add `first` directly in your helper function as:

```
$result = DB::table('tableaddress')
           ->where('id',$id)
           ->pluck('address')
           ->first();
```

Comment: error return `Call to a member function first() on array`

Comment: If it's an array then try with `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the returned result from `Helper::getAddress(112233)`